# Mocking Method Which Returns Guid With .Moq

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I am using clean architecture and creating tests for my Application layer. My problem is that the test case fails because of `_movieRepository.CreateAsync()` returns an empty `Guid` which is "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" instead of filled with "CF0A8C1C-F2D0-41A1-A12C-53D9BE513A1C"

This is the fixture class :

```
public class MovieFixture
    {
        private readonly Mock<IMovieRepository> _movieRepository = new Mock<IMovieRepository>();
        private ServiceCollection ServiceCollection { get; } = new ServiceCollection();

        public CreateMovieCommandHandler CreateMovieCommandHandler
        {
            get
            {
                ServiceProvider serviceProvider = ServiceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
                CreateMovieCommandHandler service = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<CreateMovieCommandHandler>();
                return service;
            }
        }

        public MovieFixture()
        {
            var sampleGuid = new Guid("{CF0A8C1C-F2D0-41A1-A12C-53D9BE513A1C}");
            #region Movie command handler mocks

            // Create movie.
            _movieRepository
                .Setup(x => x.CreateAsync(_successMovie.ToMovieDomainModel()))
                .ReturnsAsync(sampleGuid);

            _movieRepository
                .Setup(x => x.CreateAsync(_failedMovie))
                .ReturnsAsync(Guid.Empty);

            #endregion

            #region Add transient services
            AddServices();
            #endregion
        }

        private void AddServices()
        {
            // Add repository mock
            _ = ServiceCollection.AddTransient(_ => _movieRepository.Object);

            // Add handlers
            _ = ServiceCollection.AddTransient<CreateMovieCommandHandler>();

            // Add validator
            _ = ServiceCollection.AddTransient<MovieValidator<CreateMovieCommand>>();
        }

        private CreateMovieCommand _successMovie = new CreateMovieCommand
        {
            Name = "success",
            Description = "test",
            IsActive = true,
            IsExpired = false,
            Image = "some-image.png",
            StartDate = DateTime.Now
        };

        private Movie _failedMovie = new Movie
        {
            Name = "failed",
            Description = "test",
            IsActive = true,
            IsExpired = false,
            Image = "some-image.png",
            StartDate = DateTime.Now
        };
```

And this is the actual test case which fails

```
[Fact]
        public async Task Handle_WhenRepositoryReturnsSuccess_ShouldReturnUnitValue()
        {
            // Arrange
            Exception? exception = default;
            var handler = _movieFixture.CreateMovieCommandHandler;
            Unit result = default;

            // Act
            try
            {
                result = await handler.Handle(_successMovie, CancellationToken.None);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                exception = ex;
            }

            //Assert
            exception.Should().BeNull();
            result.Should().Be(Unit.Value);
        }
```

Here is the command handler too.

```
public async Task<Unit> Handle(CreateMovieCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var validationResult = await _validator.ValidateAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (validationResult.IsValid is false)
                throw new ValidationException(validationResult.Errors.FirstOrDefault()?.ToString());

            var result = await _movieRepository.CreateAsync(request.ToMovieDomainModel()).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (result == Guid.Empty)
                throw new MovieCannotBeAddedException(ErrorMessages.MovieCannotBeAdded);

            return Unit.Value;
        }
```

Hope someone catches the mistake and help me.

Have a great day.

I have tried `.Returns(Task.FromResult(sampleGuid));` instead of `.ReturnsAsync()` method but didn't fixed the issue. I also tried to generate the unique random `Guid.NewGuid()`, instead of variable `sampleGuid`,  for both mocks. but failed again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet that `ToDomainModel` just creates a new instance of class which does not have `Equals` overridden (so `Moq` fails to match the parameter and returns the default value for `Guid`). Change `_successMovie.ToMovieDomainModel()` in the `Setup` call to `It.IsAny<Movie>` or `It.Is` with some matching logic:

```cs
_movieRepository
    .Setup(x => x.CreateAsync(It.Is<Movie>(movie => movie.Name == _successMovie.Name)))
    .ReturnsAsync(sampleGuid);
```

In such cases sometimes can be useful to switch to strict mode (which throws when attempt is made to invoke not setup member):

> Make mock behave like a "true Mock", raising exceptions for anything that doesn't have a corresponding expectation: in Moq slang a "Strict" mock; default behavior is "Loose" mock, which never throws and returns default values or empty arrays, enumerables, etc. if no expectation is set for a member

```cs
private readonly Mock<IMovieRepository> _movieRepository = 
    new Mock<IMovieRepository>(MockBehavior.Strict);
```

Read also:

[Moq Quickstart: Matching Arguments](https://github.com/moq/moq/wiki/Quickstart#matching-arguments)

Comment: Oh, I see a problem now. Yes ToMovieDomainModel() just creates a new movie domain model with such a properties. Your solution fixed the problem, thanks.